# Writing XLSX files without having the entire object in memory at once

Tags: xlsx

I'm trying to create large XLSX files from using a 32 bit C# application. For this requirement the binary must be 32 bit (the decision isn't mine). It does however run on a 64 bit machine with 16+GB of RAM.

I have tried writing XLSX files using NPOI and EPPlus. I can write small files without issue. When I'm writing much larger data, I get issues running out of memory. The same data represented in CSV is only 80MB. I expect the XLSX objects must be massive, because I would have thought I'd have at at least a few GB of unfragmented memory free).

I've tried writing a CSV file (in this case it results in an 80MB CSV file), then using EPPlus' LoadFromText function to create an XLSX. Again that works on small files, but for an 80MB CSV it takes more than 21 hours to create the XLSX.

I'd like a scalable solution. So I can't rely on having an object that represents the entire XLSX file in memory at once. Does anyone know of a way to write XLSX files that doesn't require having an object representing the entire XLSX file in memory at once?

I *think* Perl's Excel::Writer::XLSX can do this, but I need a C# solution. One that I preferably do not need to write on my own or port from some other library.

Does anyone know of any options?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like z0mp's answer at http://epplus.codeplex.com/discussions/230092 solves the problem in a scalable manner. He first creates an Open XML document, then reads X many bytes at once and writes those to his XLSX document.